# How to center the box header text in baposter

Tags: horizontal-alignment, posters, baposter

I am writing a poster using baposter class. I want to centre the text in header box(for one particular headerbox not all). Here is the minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[pdftex, british,a0paper, fontscale=.32]{baposter}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{My Poster}
\author{Apurba Paul}
\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
{}
{\thetitle}
{theauthor}
{}}
\headerbox{Box title}{name=box1, column=0, row=0}{%
content here
}
\end{document}
```

I watn the "Box title" to be appear in the center of the box header not at the left side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All styles have its anchor hardcoded, so you should select `headershape=small-rounded` or `headershape=roundedright` which according to  `baposter_guide.pdf` gives centered box titles.

If you want to use some other style, will have to change its definition. To do this, you can look how in `baposter.cls` how are titles for boxes defined and change according to your needs.

As an example, `smallrounded` are defined (lines 685-688 from baposter.cls) with

```
\newcommand{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@smallrounded}[1]{
  \path (\baposter@box@name nw) +(0.5\boxwidth,-0.5\baposter@box@@boxheaderheight) node[anchor=center] {#1};%
}
```

while `rectangle` style is (lines 682-684)

```
\newcommand{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}[1]{
  \path (\baposter@box@name nw) +(0em,-0.5\baposter@box@@boxheaderheight) node[anchor=west,inner sep=0.4em] {#1};%
}
```

As you can see second style places title anchored to its left and at a mid point between north west (nw) and south west `(\baposter@box@name nw) +(0em,-0.5\baposter@box@@boxheaderheight)` corners of header box. While `smallrounded` style places title anchored at its center and in center point of header box. If you can obtain second effect with `rectangle` style, change its definition in your preamble with

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}[1]{
  \path (\baposter@box@name nw) +(0.5\boxwidth,-0.5\baposter@box@@boxheaderheight) node[anchor=center] {#1};%
}
\makeatother
```

and will obtain a `rectangle` header title with centered text:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, british, a0paper, fontscale=.32]{baposter}

\usepackage{titling}
\title{My Poster}
\author{Apurba Paul}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}[1]{
  \path (\baposter@box@name nw) +(0.5\boxwidth,-0.5\baposter@box@@boxheaderheight) node[anchor=center] {#1};%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{%
  background=none,
%  bgColorOne=gray!30,
  headerColorOne=blue!30,
  headershade=plain,
  boxshade=none,
  headershape=rectangle,
}
{}
{\thetitle}
{\theauthor}
{}

\headerbox{Box title}{name=box1, column=0, row=0}{content here}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, @Ignasi it is already known to me that if I use `headershape=rounded` the header will be aligned to center. But actually I was looking for a solution where I don,t have to use rounded headershape.

Comment: @Apurba: Look at updated answer. Hope it helps.